# Internal Server Error 500 in only one Storeview of Magento

Tags: session, magento

I'm running Magento 1.7.0.0 multistore and a few times a day I get the famous "Internal Server Error 500" in my browser.

- When navigating to Magento backend or a different Magento Storeview, the backend and the Storeview are still available and show no Internal Server Error.
- Visiting the homepage or any category page, product page or cms page doesn't make a difference.
- After flushing /var/sessions, the frontend is available again.

So, what I've done already:

- I think it's not related to permissions, as these are set properly. I ran Magento-Cleanup.php a few times, and that's not changing or helping.
- I checked settings in htaccess. These seem to be good.
- SID is off. With or without SID doesn't make a difference
- Logs show no issues that could cause this.

Help!

Comment: The Apache error log *will* contain a more detailed description of what went wrong.

Comment: I check this too:

Congratulations! Your server meets the requirements for Magento.

You have PHP 5.2.0 (or greater)
Safe Mode is off
You have MySQL 4.1.20 (or greater)
You have the curl extension
You have the dom extension
You have the gd extension
You have the hash extension
You have the iconv extension
You have the mcrypt extension
You have the pcre extension
You have the pdo extension
You have the pdo_mysql extension
You have the simplexml extension

Comment: Found this errors:

Premature end of script headers: index.php, (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server and client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml

Comment: this is not magento issue. Check webserver server config. Check logs for fatal errors.

Answer (score -1):

Can you change your PHP setting to use Apache rather than fastCGI? I've seen this error before with FastCGI on some servers